# How to arrive at $ \frac{\partial }{\partial X} \log(\mathrm{det}(I + A X B^\top )) = A^\top (I +B X^\top A^\top )^{-1} B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Dear Matrix Calculus experts, please do enlighten me. How to arrive at the following matrix derivative?

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial X} \log( \mathrm{det}(I + A X B^\top ) ) = A^\top (I + B X^\top A^\top )^{-1} B$$

I am in a confused state with matrix calculus because I am learning and not fully grasping the concept, I must admit. In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), it says the following:

> It is often easier to work in differential form and then convert back to normal derivatives.

My source of confusion begins from here. So, the differential is

$$\mathrm d \log(\det(X)) = \mbox{tr} \left( X^{-1} \mathrm d X \right)$$

now do we "convert" it to normal derivative such that I get my above answer? :/ I hope I will get this matrix calculus someday. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Terence Tao, [Matrix identities as derivatives of determinant identities](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/), January 13, 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than the trace function, the trace/Frobenius product notation
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ 
lends itself more readily to algebraic manipulations.

Start with the differential result that you quoted, but in terms of the variable 
$$Y=(I+AXB^T)$$
instead of $X$. Then change the variable from $Y\rightarrow X$
$$\eqalign{
 d\log\det Y
 &= Y^{-T}:dY\cr
 &= Y^{-T}:A\,dX\,B^T \cr
 &= A^TY^{-T}B:dX \cr
 &= A^T(I+BX^TA^T)^{-1}B:dX\cr
}$$
The gradient is therefore
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\log\det Y}{\partial X} &= A^T(I+BX^TA^T)^{-1}B \cr\cr
}$$
Note that the cyclic property of the trace function gives rise to many equivalent ways to arrange the terms in a Frobenius product, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= B^TAC^T:I \cr
 &= etc \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks greg. I really like your approach. must say that. Thank you so much. I have one clarification for now. Is the differential of $\log \det (X) = X^{-T} : dX$ or $\log \det (X) = X^{-1} : dX$?

Comment: I mean the following differential form you have mentioned:  $d\log\det Y= Y^{-T}:dY$ is not due to the cyclic property of $\rm tr$ function, is it?

Comment: @user550103 It's the same formula as you quoted, just reformatted as a Frobenius product $${\rm tr}(X^{-1}dX)=X^{-T}:dX$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.